# How to run a script displaying images with ssh?

Tags: python, opencv, ssh, gtk

I have a Python script, which displays images on a projector without user interaction. It calls OpenCV functions, which are using GTK backend. It runs just fine locally. When I try to run it remotely with `ssh`, I'm getting `Can't initialize GTK backend` error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) /tmp/pip-wheel-xjhn4aom/opencv-contrib-python_db9bf2c2b8dd41b592a48d20aac72627/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window_gtk.cpp:635: error: (-2:Unspecified error) Can't initialize GTK backend in function 'cvInitSystem'
```

What is the way to fix it? I don't want to see the images on the client. I want the host to display images exactly the same way as if the script was run locally.

Answer (score 1):

This probably because the server you are ssh'ing into has no X installed (the graphical environment).
Check if you have an environment variable called DISPLAY on this server.
If X is running on this server, you have to set your SSH sessions display to match the number of the running display.
Hopefully, this helps...

See also here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display

Comment: The server/host is running the full desktop (Raspberry Pi OS). I've got the script to display an image with `ssh pi@192.168.0.16 "DISPLAY=:0.0 python3 /home/pi/test.py`, but I'm not getting its output and it's not accepting keyboard input.

Comment: I'm getting the output from the script with: `ssh pi@192.168.0.16`, `export DISPLAY=:0.0`, `python3 /home/pi/test.py`, but it's not getting my keyboard input.

Comment: That's probably because showing the image is blocking. Please show us the python code.

Comment: You are right. Image display runs its own event loop on the server and expects keyboard input there. A simple test with reading/writing to terminal works just fine.